# Pass JSON parameter to Web API

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

I hope you can help me again with these, i have a c# class that contain object container, i need to populate this class object from a json object.

```
public class user { public string name {get;set;} public userAttributes {get;set;}}

public class userAttributes { int id {get; set;} string value {get;set;}}
```

I am using google postman using url-encoded option for passing a parameter and i dont know what is the exact json format to be able to get this.i am passing the userAttribute like this :

```
"userAttributes": [
{
  "Values": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "Value": "sample string 2"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "Value": "sample string 2"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: `Serialize` an object of type `userAttributes `,and you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this one,

```
public class UserAttribute
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}       
public class UserAttributes
{
    public IList<UserAttribute> UserAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

Json

```
 {"UserAttributes": [{  "Id":"1" , "Value":"sample string 1" }, 
                     {  "Id":"2" , "Value":"sample string 2" }]}
```